# How do I replace the code module in excel file with c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have to replace the code module in a number of existing excel files. Instead of opening each file, removing the VB Module and importing a new VB Module, and then saving it manually I tried to write a small program to do the work. It will prove useful in the future. But only if I can make it work! The new VB Module is a .bas file that I exported from another version of the workbook.

Here is the C# code I tried.

```
        foreach (FileInfo file in temp)
        {
            wkbk =app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:file.FullName);
            VBProject proj = wkbk.VBProject;
            foreach (VBComponent comp in proj.VBComponents)
            {
                    if(comp.Name=="VBModule") 
                        proj.VBComponents.Remove(comp);
            }
            proj.VBComponents.Import(newFile);
            wkbk.Close(SaveChanges:true, Filename:file.FullName);
            ReleaseObject(wkbk);
        }
```

Yes, the name of the module is VBModule. temp is an ObservableCollection of FileInfo objects. While stepping through, this program hits every line without an error. I just doesn't do anything. I can examine the variables and they are exactly as intended. I assume that the Save is not working so that when I examine the file it is the same as it was before running this program.

Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Does it hit the "remove" line?

Comment: Can you try specifying a NEW Filename to see if that new workbook file gets created with the expected module? If it does, that suggests a problem overwriting the original rather than any other issue...

Comment: Yes, Tim. It does. And thank you Jazimov for your suggestion. I have the answer but it is too long to post in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is in the code above. I had it right. The file I was trying to import "VBModule_Hold.bas" was being imported. But in Excel, when you examine the Modules it is only called VBModule. I named it that originally a couple years ago when I inserted the new module and started writing code. I had to make some updates that I wanted to apply to past files as well so I made the changes, exported the code module with a new name and wrote this little routine to update all the old excel files. When I examined a file after running the routine, it appeared that the module had not been removed and replaced because it was named VBModule. I assumed nothing had been changed. I suppose it has to do with the _ in the file name. Anyway, I edited my "Hold" module with an obvious comment at the top. I ran the code, opened the Excel file and examined the module. There was my comment! My thanks to the responses I got. Jazimov made me look at the file in a different way that led me to the answer. I saved it as "NewFile.xlsm" and there it was. Thank you both, again.